# Count Distinct in dtypes of a pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I need a function to get something like this in a pypspark dataframe:

Variables types:

Numeric:    4
Categorical:    4
Date:   1

Answer (score 1):

Let's create a dummy Dataframe in our Pyspark Shell

`>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([['x',1,'y',2,1.1]])`

`>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, schema=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'])`

Here are the column types for df

`>>> df
DataFrame[Col1: string, Col2: bigint, Col3: string, Col4: bigint, Col5: double]`

As per the documentation, if you use the dtypes attribute on a Spark DataFrame, https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.dtypes you will get "all column names and their data types as a list"

`>>> print(df.dtypes)
[('Col1', 'string'), ('Col2', 'bigint'), ('Col3', 'string'), ('Col4', 'bigint'), ('Col5', 'double')]`

You can now leverage the native Python Counter Library to get your desired output

`>>> from Collections import Counter`

`>>> data_types = df.dtypes`

`>>> dict(Counter(dict(data_types).values()))
{'string': 2, 'bigint': 2, 'double': 1}`

You should be easily able to convert these two lines into a function that meets your end requirements

Hope this helps!